# Can I draw faces, portraits or humans

Tags: drawing

I recently learned that drawing or some drawing in a sin in islam. I would like to know what is okay and what isn't in drawing.

Answer (score 0):

ONE VIEW POINT FROM ISLAMQA:

"Drawing is of two types:

One is drawing pictures of animate beings. It says in the Sunnah that this is forbidden. It is not permitted to draw anything that depicts animate beings, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, according to the saheeh hadeeth: “Every image maker will be in the Fire.” And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The most severely punished of people on the Day of Resurrection will be the image-makers, those who tried to imitate the creation of Allaah.” And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The makers of these images will be punished on the Day of Resurrection, and they will be told, ‘Give life to that which you have created.’”

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) cursed those who consume riba (interest, usury) and those who pay it, and he cursed the image-makers. This indicates that making images is forbidden. The scholars interpreted that as referring to images of animate beings such as animals, people and birds.

With regard to drawing inanimate objects – which is the second type of drawing – there is no sin in that, such as drawing mountains, trees, planes, cars and the like. There is nothing wrong with that, according to the scholars.

With regard to forbidden kinds of pictures, an exception is made in cases of necessity, such as drawing pictures of criminals so that they will be known and caught, or pictures for identity cards which are essential and which cannot be obtained otherwise, and other cases of necessity.  If the ruler  decides that producing images of criminals is necessary, because of the seriousness of their crimes and  to protect the Muslims from their evil when they are known, or for other reasons, there is nothing wrong with that. Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):

“…He has explained to you in detail what is forbidden to you, except under compulsion of necessity …”

[al-An’aam 6:119] "

AN OPPOSING VIEW POINT IS that drawing animate object (so humans) is NOT forbidden (haram) and only the act of create mimications of the depictions of holy figures, so drawing pictures of any prophet (as/saw) or allah (swa) is haram. I would be encouraging somebody to believe this viewpoint, even when given no Hadith as evidence, just because even during the times of the prophets (as/saw) Muslim  people were creating images of each other and the animal kingdom, this has carried on for hundreds of years and is even embedded in some Asian Islamic cultures.

It is up to you what you choose to believe with the evidence you research and read. Remember allah (swa) is all forgiving and accepting and will greet you with warmth and love no matter what you choose to believe as long as you believe in Him and the prophet (saw).

Comment: Thank you for this, I might add in the hadith does image maker mean idol maker? Because idol worshiping was heavy at that time, could the prophet (SWA) mean that?

Comment: Again, I have no intentions of worship to portraits, nor do I see myself as the creater because I know Allah is the creater.